# PHP: $_SESSION register

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm having problem with this code and I can't figure out where the problem is. So when I run this code: `if $row["count"] > 0` the `else` block is run and `$_SESSION["error"]` is set.

When `$row["count"] == 0` query is executed and new row is inserted into database but both `$_SESSION["save"]` and `$_SESSION["error"]` are set! Does this mean that both `if` and `else` statements are run? It doesn't make any sense to me...

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ... QUERY");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if( $row["count"] == 0 ){
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT...QUERY");
    $stmt->execute();
    $_SESSION["save"] = "Saved";
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit();
}else{
    $_SESSION["error"] = "Error";
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit();
}
```

i'm using this code in index.php

```
$save = (isset($_SESSION["save"]))? $_SESSION["save"] : false;
$error = (isset($_SESSION["error"]))? $_SESSION["error"] : false;
unset($_SESSION["error"]);
unset($_SESSION["save"]);
```

As I said, when `$row["count"] == 0` I have both `$save` and `$error` set..

SOLVED
It appears that I found the problem. I've changed they way I access the script from:

```
<a href='script.php?id=10'><input type="button" value='Go to script' /></a>
```

to:

```
<a href='script.php?id=10'>Go to script</a>
```

And the script is working now. With the input button tag inside the a tag the script was behaving unpredictable executing the `if` and `else` statement in the same time.. I'm still confused why and how input tag caused that, but at least the script is working now...

Answer (score 2):

Are you clearing `$_SESSION["error"]` and `$_SESSION["save"]` after they have been read in `index.php`? It sounds to me like you have run across both cases once and have lingering values in your `$_SESSION` array.

I suggest using the same variable name for both cases, e.g. `$_SESSION['save']`, and assigning either `success` or `error` to it. That way, you don't have to check whether one of two variables exist, but only what its contents are.

And don't forget to clear or unset the variable after it has served its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

FOr example, when you trying this, if in a stage `$row["count"] > 0` session will record `$_SESSION["error"]` . It will be stored if you don't delete it. Because of this `$_SESSION["error"]` is setted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have executed your code twice and ["error"] was still set. You dont clear it on success.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic, it is impossible for both conditions to run at the same time.  However, I'm sure you've run this script multiple times.  Sometimes with IF, sometimes with ELSE.  It doesn't seem like you're ever clearing the $_SESSION variables.

Solution:
Right after you use the $_SESSION['save'] or $_SESSION['error'] variables, unset them.

```
unset($_SESSION['save']);
```

or

```
unset($_SESSION['error]');
```